# Путь к файлу с помощью Path

Tags: java

Как объект Path, который указывает путь к файлу `ttt.txt`, который в свою очередь находится в папке `res`, расположенной в родительской папке относительно исполняемого файла?

Comment: У вас глагол опущен. Как объект Path что? Мысленно обрежьте вопрос после слова Path - и вы сами увидите, что у вас вопрос не дописан.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй получить либо абсолютный путь и оттуда уже убрав последний каталог получишь родительский (и для этого есть `getAbsolutePath()`), ну или `java.io.File.getParent ()`, который сразу возвращает путь к родительскому каталогу, и просто прибавить к нему `res\ttt.txt`